# How to submit a form in a directive from some where (another method) using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to submit a form in a directive from some where (another method) using AngularJs. Here I have added my code. I need to call this export submit from different places. This form submission is the best way to to export number of records. Please give solution for this.  Thanks in advance.

```
App.directive('exportData',function(){
      return {
        restrict : 'AE',
        templateUrl: "ajs/views/exportData.html",
        controller: 'exportDataController'
    }
});

exportData.html

<form method=post id='export_lead' class='leadExport' action='/app/dao/test?a=bulkExport'><input type='hidden' name='ids' id='ids' value='" + JSON.stringify(ids) + "'></form>

// from controller
$scope.exportLeads = function(type, reportData)
{
    // Here I need to call form submit.
    angular.element(document.getElementById('export_lead')).triggerHandler('click');
};
```

Comment: I'm confused, you have a directive which renders a form with nothing in it but a hidden button, and you want to trigger the click on the hidden button?

Comment: Hi claies... I want to submit a form. How to do that?